# Syntax for partition with subpartition

Tags: sql, oracle

```
col1 ....
col2 ....
col3 ....
col4 ....
PARTITION BY RANGE(DATE_KEY)
SUBPARTITION BY LIST(REGION_KEY)
SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE
  (SUBPARTITION A VALUES (1) TABLESPACE X,
   SUBPARTITION B VALUES(3) TABLESPACE X,
   SUBPARTITION C VALUES (8) TABLESPACE X)
(PARTITION MON_JAN_2012 VALUES LESS THAN (1000)
    TABLESPACE X
    PCTFREE 10
    INITRANS 1
    MAXTRANS 255
    NOLOGGING
  (SUBPARTITION A VALUES (1) TABLESPACE X,
   SUBPARTITION B VALUES(3) TABLESPACE X,
   SUBPARTITION C VALUES (8) TABLESPACE X),
 PARTITION MON_FEB_2012 VALUES LESS THAN (2000)
    TABLESPACE X        PCTFREE 10
    INITRANS 1
    MAXTRANS 255
    NOLOGGING
  (SUBPARTITION A VALUES (1) TABLESPACE X,
   SUBPARTITION B VALUES(3) TABLESPACE X,
   SUBPARTITION C VALUES (8) TABLESPACE X)
```

My table structure is something like this, I m new to partitions, need to add new partitions for table from March_2021 for few months, need correct syntax for this, I tried to google but not able to find example for adding partition with subpartition. Database 10g

Comment: If you're partitioning by DATE_KEY with partitions which are named after months why is the RANGE VALUES clause specified as a *number* rather than a *date* ?

Comment: Table sctructure is that, we are generating a unqiue value for each date. Its an integer value for DATE_KEY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a template, adding partitions is transparent to subpartitions:

```
alter table your_table add partition mon_mar_2012 values less than (3000);
```

(This will automaticaly creates subpartitions for the new partition).

**EDIT**: if you wouldn't have had template, you should have create subpartitions manualy:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY PARTITION partition
      ADD SUBPARTITION subpartition_name ...
```

Comment: Thanks. works like a charm. If template is not available then I need to define subpartition each time, correct?

Comment: @FlorinGhita What if I have 250 RANGE partitions. Its not optimum solution to include 250 alter statements and add the same sub-partition to those partitions?

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy Have you tried to modify the template? (it's not a problem to add 250 subpartitions. You do it once, not every day.)